# How to get absolute path on a zsh prompt?

Tags: zsh

I'm switching from bash to zsh.

I want to update my new zsh prompt and looked around to find a way, but I have only found "solutions" via oh-my-zsh.

**The goal:**

```
Location: ~/dir_1/dir_1_1/dir_1_1_1
```

**What I have:**

```
Location: dir_1_1_1
```

The code [(source)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/configs/prompt.zsh#L9):

```
 PS1='${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[green]%}Location: %c%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) '
```

Comment: `dir_1/dir_1_1/dir_1_1_1` is not full path. Not sure what you want, but most people use `%~` or `%n~` instead of `%c`, where `n` is the number of trailing components to show. `%c` is deprecated anyway. Read http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html.

Comment: Thanks @4ae1e1 that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Horacio Chavez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043906/horacio-chavez) mentioned in the comment above, you want to look here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html for the details on how to change your displayed path in zsh.

In this case if you are looking for a path that is relative to your home folder, include a `%~` in your zsh-theme file. Your prompt would now look like this:

```
PS1='${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[green]%}Location: %~%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) '
```

note, I only changed one character in your prompt. the `%c` was swapped for the `%~`. `%c` will only give your current directory ([see the document link above, or here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html))

For a full path you could use `%/`

Answer (score 27):

**To preserve original prompt format** (colors, git info and potentially other customisations before this one) except related to path info, you could append following to the end of ~/.zshrc:

```sh
PROMPT=${PROMPT/\%c/\%~}
```

> As pointed out by [@caleb-adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704230/caleb-adams) and [@fend25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2061583/fend25) the key is replacing `%c` (just folder name) with `%~` to include full path (or absolute from $HOME when under ~). See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html for more info

Comment: This didn't work for me, on zsh v5.8.1. I added this to my .zshrc and then re-sourced it, but the prompt is still not showing the full path.

Comment: This also straightforwardly does not work for me on zsh 5.9

Answer (score 15):

Simplest way to add bash-style dir path to the prompt. Just add this to `~/.zshrc`:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%n@%m: ${(%):-%~} '
```

The part with the path is `${(%):-%~}`. Colouring could be added according with your lifestyle:)

Answer (score 0):

```
export PROMPT=${PROMPT//\%c/\%d}
```

Just append above code into `.zshrc` and source again.

Because `%c` behalf of name and `%d` is full path.